# How to change MutableArray from other view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my Application,

There are two different views **ItemList** And **ItemSearch**.

In ItemList file I have one `NsMutableArray` with name `tblItem`. I want pass data in `tblitem` from the `Itemsearch` page.

How can I do this?

Comment: How you are navigating from ItemSearch to ItemList?

Comment: Uh, pass the address of the NSMutableArray to the other view?

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:ItemListPage animated:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of properties as follows:

1.Create a property in ItemList.h of tblItem as,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tblItem;
```

then synthesize it in ItemList.m,

```
@synthesize tblItem;
```

When you are navigating from ItemSearch to ItemList ie when you are initializing ItemList just provide tblItem the required values as,

```
ItemListObj.tblItem = theSearchedArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare an NSMutableArray as property in the SecondViewController and assign the array at the time you are pushing or presenting the SecondViewController from the FirstViewController.

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray    *aryFromFirstViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray  *aryFromFirstViewController;


@end
```

At the implementation, synthesize the property

```
@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize aryFromFirstViewController;

@end
```

At the header of the FirstViewController import the SecondViewController

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
```

At implementation of the FirstViewController, add the code like below in where you wrote the code to present or push the SecondViewController

```
@implementation FirstViewController


- (void) functionForPushingTheSecondViewController
{
     SecondViewController *objSecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNIBName: @"SecondViewController" bundle: nil];
     objSecondViewController.aryFromFirstViewController = self.myAryToPass;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondViewController animated: YES];
     [objSecondViewController release];
}

@end
```

Please don't forget to release the `aryFromFirstViewController` at `dealloc` method of SecondViewController, otherwise it will leak because we retained it. I'l feel good if i come to know that this helped you in someways. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your need. You can use Singleton class for sharing of your variables between different classes. Define all variable which you wants share in your DataClass.

in .h file (where RootViewController is my DataClass, replace name with your new class)

```
+(RootViewController*)sharedFirstViewController;
```

in .m file

```
//make the class singleton:-    
+(RootViewController*)sharedFirstViewController    
{    
@synchronized([RootViewController class])
 {
    if (!_sharedFirstViewController)
        [[self alloc] init];

    return _sharedFirstViewController;
}

return nil;
}


+(id)alloc
{
@synchronized([RootViewController class])
{
    NSAssert(_sharedFirstViewController == nil, 
             @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
    _sharedFirstViewController = [super alloc];
    return _sharedFirstViewController; 
}
return nil;
}

-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    // initialize stuff here
}
return self;
}
```

after that you can use your variable in any other class like this

```
[RootViewController sharedFirstViewController].variable
```

Hope it's help you:)